# Touchscreen Calibration (xinput_calibrator cannot find device)

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

I followed these calibration instructions from the [manufacturer](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)).

I have attempted to calibrate from the command line

```
usr@hostname:~ $ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
usr@hostname:~ $ sudo DISPLAY=:0.0 xinput_calibrator
Error: No calibratable devices found.
usr@hostname:~ $
```

And attemping to calibrate from the gui(menu->preferences->calibrate touchscreen), I receive the same error.

What is going on here? The display variable exists and the screen otherwise works.

Waveshare 5inch HDMI LCD (B)

Raspberry Pi 3 kernel 4.14.27-v7+

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your micro USB cords y'all!

Not all usb cords transfer data. The screen was receiving power (backlight on) but the Pi was unable to communicate with the touch screen.

Changed the cord and the Pi is able to find the device.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please use proper language in your answers. You are answering your own question... is this the correct answer? Is this what your problem was? please specify...